# Why does this model have softmax layer?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, convolution, softmax

[image: Object Detection]

This picture is from this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02300v2.pdf. I could not understand what is the functionality of softmax in this model. If our goal is to find the bounding boxes for object detection, why do we use softmax at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Softmax is applied to class based output (look at the graph, it is not boundig box output!). Boundig box output does not use softmax but rather normal output + L1 loss.

Comment: So can we say softmax is used just to get objectness scores ? There is not much detail about that in the paper which makes me confused. @Iejlot

Comment: yes, using terms from the paper it is for output of "objectness"

Comment: I thought after softmax layer we will have 20 different probability values which shows for example the bounding box is table with 0.75 probability, it is a chair with 0.25 probability etc. However, what are my ygold values to classify these bounding boxes? Are we going to use the anchors as ygold values?

Comment: this is precisely described in the paper - regression on page 5, cummulative cost on page 6